# onPostExecute() not related to doInBackground() while debugging

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-room, android-jetpack

I have a problem with my `onPostExecute()` method in `AsyncTask` class.

I have an **`SignupActivity`**:

```
public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SignupListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup_activity);

    //new task, i pass context and interface to it
    signup = new Signup(getApplicationContext(), this);

    signupButon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(validate()) {
                try {
                    //new task every click
                    Signup newSignup = new Signup(signup);
                    //here start AsyncTask
                    newSignup.execute(name, email, password).get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ERROR);
                }
                // if sign up succes, == true;
                if(signupValid) {
                    Toast.makeText(SUCCES);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ERROR);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

// my own interface for getting result as bool from onPostExecute
@Override
public void onSignupPerformed(Boolean result){ this.signupValid = result; }
```

That implements my interface to catching result from `onPostExecute()`:

```
public interface SignupListener{
    void onSignupPerformed(Boolean result);
}
```

Now, **`AsyncTask`** that i trigger in code:

```
public class Signup extends AsyncTask<String,  Boolean, Boolean> {

public Signup(Context context, SignupListener listener){
    db = ApplicationDatabase.getDatabase(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
}

public Signup(Signup signup){
    //constructor to make new task based on first task
    db = signup.db;
    context = signup.context;
    listener = signup.listener;
}

protected Boolean doInBackground(String... body){
    try {
            user = db.userDao().getUser(body[0], body[1], body[2]);
            if (user == null) {
                // user is null, so we can add new one to DB
                db.userDao().insertUser(new User(body[0], body[1], body[2]));
                return Boolean.TRUE; //signup go good, return true
            } else {
                return Boolean.FALSE; //signup go bad, return false
            }
    } catch(Exception e) { }
        return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    //catching result from doInBackground
    listener.onSignupPerformed(result);
}
```

My question is, why when i first click on button, func return `Boolean.TRUE` but in `SignupActivity` `signupValid` variable is `false` (signup form not exit, but user is added to DB), but when i click signup button second time, ofc signup fail (because we make new user seconds ago) but `signupValid` change to `true` and Signup Form pass? I need to click `SignupButton` two times to finally exit form. Thanks for finding error in my code

**EDIT:**

I replaced `.get()` with `Progress Dialog` to block UI, but now i get `Toast` with not valid form even before `AsyncTask` for Signup do his job. And still, in first click `signupValid` is false even when from `doInBackground()` i get `TRUE`, on second click `AsyncTask` return `FALSE` but `signupValid` is changed to `true`

My **UserDAO:**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password AND username = :username")
    User getUser(String username, String email, String password);
}
```

And **ApplicationDatabase:**

```
public abstract class ApplicationDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract UserDao userDao();

public static ApplicationDatabase getDatabase(final Context context){
    if(INSTANCE == null){
        synchronized (ApplicationDatabase.class){
            if(INSTANCE == null){
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), ApplicationDatabase.class, "database").build();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

private static volatile ApplicationDatabase INSTANCE;
```

Comment: Don't use `.get()` on an AsyncTask. It completely invalidates the point of using one. Put the check in `onSignupPerformed()`.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? What to change first?

Comment: When i dont use `.get()`, i get my error about `not valid form` before `task` end

Comment: Remove get and in the empty catch log any exception that may be occurring. Fix the problem don't patch it.

Comment: Ok, i can delete `get()` and block UI by `Progress dialog`, but then i get `Toast.(Error)` before `AsyncTask` do his work (error that tells to user, that his signup form was not valid, but form was valid)

Comment: i edited my post

Comment: Are you sure that `getUser` is not an async method as well?

Comment: @ymz look into my edit. I posted my DB and UserDao. You want to tell me, that `getUser` in this case should be async too? I think its not a case. i juz get wrong return from `onPostExecute()`. From `doInBackground` i get `TRUE`, but to context is passing `false`. After second run (with new task, u see it in code on button click) from `doInBackground` i get `false`, but in `signupValid` i get `true`. I do this two clicks without changing my signup form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly - there is a race condition that makes the `SignupActivity` to fire the toast before the execution of `Signup` task is completed. Therefore:

```
signupButon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(validate()) {
            try {
                //new task every click
                Signup newSignup = new Signup(signup);
                //here start AsyncTask
                newSignup.execute(name, email, password).get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ERROR);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

While these lines:

```
 // if sign up succes, == true;
 if(signupValid) {
    Toast.makeText(SUCCES);
    finish();
 } else {
    Toast.makeText(ERROR);
 }
```

Should be a part of the `listener` (right now it seems that these lines are executed BEFORE the completion of your async task)

To clarify myself:

```
@Override
public void onSignupPerformed(Boolean result)
{ 
     if(result) {
        Toast.makeText(SUCCES);
        finish();
     } else {
        Toast.makeText(ERROR);
     }

}
```

Comment: Make sense. I will check it in a minutes, if it will work, i will mark it as answet

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks